# Created the same program where one uses generics and the other ints but the generics one does not work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics

I am creating a program for class that sorts a 2D array faster than my teacher's implementation.

I decided to put the data into a BST and then remove each minimum element and put it into a new sorted array. However, I've been having trouble with it so I wrote it using int instead of T, when I did this the program worked!

However, now that I converted it to use the generic type T, it is no longer sorting correctly. The class below is what I've written and inherits the method sort(T[][] input) from my teacher's class HybridSort.

I believe my problem lies somewhere in the way I've been dealing with the generic type T and treating it as an int (I use x.compareTo(y) so I don't believe that is the problem). I can also post the code I wrote using int if necessary. Thanks!

```
public class ***<T extends Comparable<T>> implements HybridSort<T> {

public class BST {
    public T value;
    public BST left;
    public BST right;
    public BST root;

    public BST() {
        this.value = null;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public BST(T value, BST left, BST right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void insert(T value) {
        root = insert(root, new BST(value, null, null));
        this.value = root.value;
        this.left = root.left;
        this.right = root.right;
    }

    public BST insert(BST parent, BST newIndex) {
        if (parent == null) return newIndex;
        else if (newIndex.value.compareTo(parent.value) != 1) parent.left = insert(parent.left, newIndex);
        else if (newIndex.value.compareTo(parent.value) > 0) parent.right = insert(parent.right, newIndex);
        return parent;
    }

    public T removeMin() {
        BST current = root;
        BST parent = root;

        while (current.left != null) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.left;
        }
        parent.left = current.left;

        return current.value;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T[] sort(T[][] input) {
    BST bst = new BST();
    int size = Arrays.stream(input).mapToInt(t -> t.length).sum();
    T[] output = (T[])Array.newInstance(input[0][0].getClass(), size);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input[0].length; j++) {
            bst.insert(input[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (T)(Integer)bst.removeMin();
    }

    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated to error, but you should have two classes, one for the tree and one for the nodes. Having each node pretend to be the entire tree is going to be confusing in how you use it, since calling `insert(T)` on a node may actually insert the value in a totally different, unrelated place.

Comment: can you provide a unit test with the example input you are testing against, that is the input and the output of the `int` implementation and the generic `T` implementation

Comment: The fact that you are doing the type-cast `(Integer)` is surely a reason not to work with non-`Integer` types. Note that you should limit the scope of a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` as much as possible. So instead of applying it to the entire method, you should only apply it to the single line where it is unavoidable: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T[] output = (T[])Array.newInstance(input[0][0].getClass(), size);`. Then, your stunt of casting `T` to `Integer` and back to `T` doesn’t stay unnoticed.

Comment: using this code `@Test
  public void sort_test() {
    String[][] input = new String[][] {{"d", "c"}, {"b", "a"}};
    String[] expected = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    String[] actual = new WTF<String>().sort(input);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
  }
` and removing the type case @Holger mentions yields the expected result.